# Arsclassica (pdflatex-dependent) and unicode symbols

Tags: pdftex, unicode, classicthesis, unicode-math

I know that to use unicode symbols, I need `unicode-math` and that requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I have previously set up my own package (mostly macros) that uses `unicode-math` and runs on LuaLaTeX.

Now, I am using the [arsclassica](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica?lang=en) package (a `classicthesis` style-up) to write my thesis, and it requires pdfLaTeX which is incompatible with `unicode-math`. But I need unicode symbols as the macros I made won't work otherwise; for example, `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*\pi{\symup{π}}}` or `\DeclareMathOperator{\laplacian}{\symbol{8710}}`, etc. I have a lot of macros and I'd rather not have to figure out all over again how to change each individual one so that it works in pdfLaTeX. How can I generally work around this (i.e. modify my macros using maybe 2/3 basic commands or rules) so that the macros work as intended?

Comment: why does arsclassica require pdflatex? It is probably easier to make that work with luatex than to set up unicode input for math in pdflatex

Comment: Untested, but do the instructions at [Using the classicthesis package with XeLaTeX](https://alexkrispin.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/using-the-classicthesis-package-with-xelatex/) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you think `arsclassica` is not compatible with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{Iwona}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*\pi{\symup{π}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\laplacian}{\symbol{8710}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some title}

\section{A title}

Some text to see what happens; let's say that
$\laplacian\pi=0$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I swear on my life there was a reason it didn't work before! Thank you :) Also, the text rendering looks a bit different between using pdflatex and xe/lualatex -- any way to make it look like the pdflatex version? It seems a bit cleaner I think...